# Highlighting the matching html cell with select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to highlight the html cell with the matching value with the selectbox at the top. At the moment it only highlights the row. Can I get a little help, please?

What I try to do here is when a number is selected from selectbox, the corresponding cell with the matching value to be highlighted. I'd like to highlight more than one cell at the same time. Notice that they are two different tables.

This is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h740wt3x/).

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<table class="table1">

<tr>

<td><select name="list1" id="list1">
        <option value="">List</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
</select>   
</td>
<td><select name="list2" id="list2">
        <option value="">List</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
</select>   
</td>

<td><select name="list3" id="list3">
        <option value="">List</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
</select>   
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="table2">

<tr class="row">
<td value="1"> 1 </td>
<td value="11">11</td>
<td value="21">21 </td>
</tr>

<tr class="row">
<td value="2"> 2 </td>
<td value="12">12 </td>
<td value="22">22 </td>
</tr>

<tr class="row">
<td value="3"> 3 </td>
<td value="13">13 </td>
<td value="23">23 </td>
</tr>

</table>

</div>
```

Css code:

```
.table1,td {
    border:1px solid #999;
}

.table1 td {
    width:150px;
}


.table2,td {
    border:1px solid #999;
}

.table2 td {
    width:150px;
}
```

Jquery code:

```
$("#list1").change(function () {

   var index = this.value - 1;

    var $rows = $('.row', '.table2');

    $rows.css('background-color', '');

    $('.row', '.table2').eq(index).css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

Comment: Please don't post links to 3rd party sites, those links could die or that site could be inaccessible in the future when someone comes across this question.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this by using the `.each()` method to iterate over all cells, testing for value matches on each cell base on the currect `<select />` value. Something along the lines of this might work for you:

```js
// Apply to all selectors
$("select").change(function () {

  // Extract the index of the select being interacted with
  var selectIndex = $(this).parent().index();
  
  var value = $(this).val();
 
  // Iterate each cell of the table
  $('td', '.table2').each(function() {

    // If the cell index matches the index of the corresponding
    // selected drop down then update it's background color    
   if($(this).index() === selectIndex) {
      
      // If a value match is found, apply background color. Other
      // wise clear the background color
      if($(this).attr('value') ==  value) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
      }
      else {
       $(this).css('background-color', '');
      }
    }
    
  })
});
```

```css
.table1,td {
    border:1px solid #999;
}

.table1 td {
    width:150px;
}


.table2,td {
    border:1px solid #999;
}

.table2 td {
    width:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<table class="table1">

<tr>

<td>
    <select name="list1" id="list1">
        <option value="">List</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>   
</td>
<td>
    <select name="list2" id="list2">
        <option value="">List</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
    </select>   
</td>
<td>
    <select name="list3" id="list3">
        <option value="">List</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
    </select>   
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="table2">

<tr class="row">
<td value="1"> 1 </td>
<td value="11">11</td>
<td value="21">21 </td>
</tr>

<tr class="row">
<td value="2"> 2 </td>
<td value="12">12 </td>
<td value="22">22 </td>
</tr>

<tr class="row">
<td value="3"> 3 </td>
<td value="13">13 </td>
<td value="23">23 </td>
</tr>

</table>

</div>
```

Hope this helps! ([here's a jsfiddle as well](https://jsfiddle.net/kb51yn6t/))

Comment: Thanks, Dacre. Is it possible to select more than one cells at the same time?

Comment: I mean, is it possible to highlight values on different columns at the same time? not in the same column.

Comment: Hey, so allow for one cell to be highlighted "per-column" ?

Comment: @user223549 sure - just updated answer, does this help?

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot!

Comment: @user223549 great! glad I could help :-)